# Git files status of merge commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

What do the file status mean in git merge commits? Such as "MM", "MA", "AM"? One can see them using `git log --merges --name-status -c`

One of the commits is like:

```
commit 6be3b2d7d24e0ca90260d422b5e77775d88f459f
Merge: 64c222b 87a5495
Author: Zhongpeng Lin <zpl@zebra.propulsion.lab>
Date:   Sat May 4 14:49:49 2013 -0700

    refactor oauth to use events

MM      GameClient/src/GameClient.as
MM      GameClient/src/events/GameEvent.as
MM      GameClient/src/network/GSClient.as
MM      GameClient/src/network/OAuth.as
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MM` means that this file was modified with respect to parent 1 and also modified with respect to parent 2.

The `AM` status means that the file has been modified on disk since we last added it.

Other status codes can be interpreted as follows:

> - ' ' = unmodified
> - M = modified
> - A = added
> - D = deleted
> - R = renamed
> - C = copied
> - U = updated but unmerged